# how to get first text node while bypassing <b> and <i>?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the first text node from a string but it may contain few tags like `<b>,<i>` and `<span>`. I have tried it like this but it gives only `login` whereas it should give `login<b>user</b> account`

```
var s = $.trim('login<b>user</b> account<tbody> <tr> <td class="translated">Lorem ipsum dummy text</td></tr><tr><td class="translated">This is a new paragraph</td></tr><tr><td class="translated"><b>Email</b></td></tr><tr><td><i>This is yet another text</i></td> </tr></tbody>');

if( $(s).find('*').andSelf().not('b,i').length > 1 ) {

   if( s.substring( 0, s.indexOf('<') ) != '') {
        alert(s.substring(0, s.indexOf('<')));
    } else {
        alert($(s).find('*:not(:empty)').first().text());
    }
}
```

[check it on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Apq5W/)

**Note:**

This string will be dynamic, so write generic answer not specific to this text only.

**More Information :**

@Jeremy J Starcher! I just want to get the first non-empty text node of iframe being clicked. This node will include `<b> or <i>` and whatever is in between them like this:

```
hi my <b>bold</b> text is here // note the bold tags as it is
```

If only one element is clicked then its text is thrown but if there are more than then one elements selected then it must get the very first text node among all the nodes.

Comment: You will probably have to iterate over the child nodes until you reach the first non-`<b>` or (inclusive) non-`<i>` element.

Comment: Why not simply `$(s).find(":not(tbody)").text()`? As an aside, bare text next to a `<tbody>` surely will not result in valid markup?

Comment: Its will not be a static string, I just use this for demonstration, so cannot stick to tbody

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a brute method but you can take out all the tags you're expecting to occur in the first node and read until the start of the next tag like so:

```
text = text.replace("<b>"," ");
text = text.replace("</b>"," ");
text = text.replace("<i>"," ");
text = text.replace("</i>"," ");
text = text.replace("<span>"," ");
text = text.replace("</span>"," ");

text = text.substr(0, text.indexOf("<"));
```

Comment: you are right, but it has one more part "text" may include some tags like <b>, <i> and <span>

Comment: Started looking into regex methods but I realized there could be a simpler solution I updated my answer

Comment: No , i need result to be like this "login<b>user</b>"

Comment: You could take the first two words of the result and reformat them accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully follow the question, but if you are trying to extract the text from a DOM element, this may help:

```
  var getText = function (el) {
    var ret;
    var txt = [],
      i = 0;

    if (!el) {
      ret = "";
    } else if (el.nodeType === 3) {
      // No problem if it's a text node
      ret = el.nodeValue;
    } else {
      // If there is more to it, then let's gather it all.
      while (el.childNodes[i]) {
        txt[txt.length] = getText(el.childNodes[i]);
        i++;
      }
      // return the array as a string
      ret = txt.join("");
    }
    return ret;
  };
```